# Can't find Ubuntu iso when using wubi_uefi to install elementary os

Tags: install

As topic. No USB drive so thought I'd try this. Have downloaded the ISO, installed using Wubi, but first boot fails with an error that recommends running chkdsk /r. Have done this and still no dice. Using most recent version of elementary and Wubi Urdu.

Comment: According to wikipage (https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#various-distrosversions) this software can be used to install Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Budgie. Are you sure that Wubi_uefi supports elementary OS distro?

Comment: Yes, any ISO file downloaded into the same directory is automatically selected when wubi_uefi is launched. There are several user reports (on Reddit) of Elementary OS being installable in this way, which is why I tried in the first place.